# ¿Cómo realizar un ejemplo de animacion o transicion de botón al pulsarlo?

Tags: android, botón, layout, transicion, animación

En Android estoy tratando de que al pulsar un botón me lleve a una activity ( lo consigo gracias a este tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VUPM387qyrw&t=774s)

El caso es que estoy intentando que al pulsar un botón, por ejemplo el primero de arriba a la izquierda, **me haga un zoom y me lleve a la siguiente activity o sencillamente que realice la sensación de que es pulsado**, lo típico de que se va para atrás con cierta profundidad.

Aquí dejo el XML principal:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:weightSum="10"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textGrid"
        android:text="GRID LAYOUT"
        android:textSize="34sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>

<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainGrid"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:rowCount="3"
    android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
    android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
    android:layout_weight="8"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:padding="14dp"
    >

    <!-- Row 1 -->

    <!-- Column 1 -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/me_time"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:text="Me"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <!-- Column 2 -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/family_time"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:text="Family"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


    <!-- Row 2 -->

    <!-- Column 1 -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/lovely_time"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:text="Lovely"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <!-- Column 2 -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/team_time"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:text="Team"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


    <!-- Row 2 -->

    <!-- Column 1 -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/friends"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:text="Friends"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <!-- Column 2 -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/calendar"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:text="Calendars"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/calendar"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:text="Calendars"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/calendar"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:text="Calendars"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/calendar"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:text="Calendars"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/calendar"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:text="Calendars"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/calendar"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:text="Calendars"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/calendar"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:text="Calendars"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</GridLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Así es como queda:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y aquí el .java:

`public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {`

```
GridLayout mainGrid;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mainGrid = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainGrid);

    //Set Event
    setSingleEvent(mainGrid);
    //setToggleEvent(mainGrid);
}

private void setToggleEvent(GridLayout mainGrid) {
    //Loop all child item of Main Grid
    for (int i = 0; i < mainGrid.getChildCount(); i++) {
        //You can see , all child item is CardView , so we just cast object to CardView
        final CardView cardView = (CardView) mainGrid.getChildAt(i);
        cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (cardView.getCardBackgroundColor().getDefaultColor() == -1) {
                    //Change background color
                    cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF6F00"));
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "State : True", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else {
                    //Change background color
                    cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "State : False", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

private void setSingleEvent(GridLayout mainGrid) {
    //Loop all child item of Main Grid
    for (int i = 0; i < mainGrid.getChildCount(); i++) {
        //You can see , all child item is CardView , so we just cast object to CardView
        CardView cardView = (CardView) mainGrid.getChildAt(i);
        final int finalI = i;
        cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ActivityOne.class);
                intent.putExtra("info","This is activity from card item index  "+finalI);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Podrías agregarle el efecto de ondulación a tu `CardView` agregando estos atributos: `...
  android:clickable="true"
  android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">
  ...`

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo un ejemplo de como realizar el efecto que comentas únicamente debes jugar con el scale del archivo btn_anim para incrementarlo o disminuirlo según prefieras

**btn_anim.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<scale
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:toXScale="0.5"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="0.5"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="500"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:repeatCount="1"
    />
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button mButton;
private Animation mBtnAnim;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mButton = findViewById(R.id.btn);
    mBtnAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.btn_anim);

    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mButton.startAnimation(mBtnAnim);
        }
    });
}
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

@ALL ¿Como puedo incrustar la animación en la respuesta?

[Ejemplo](https://gfycat.com/greedytendercoyote)